# How to get response for multiple values

Tags: java, json, parent-child

I have a class for which when I pass the id I get the response but if the excel sheet has multiple banks than I can see the response in json format with mutiple values but when I run my code I get only one bank instead of mutiple banks in postman response.

```
public BankDetails getRes(List<Banks> res){
BankExcel bank = new BankExcel();
bank.setName(res.listIterator().next.getName());
bank.setAddress(res.listIterator().next.getAddress());
BankParent ban = bank;
BankDetails bankDetails = new BankDetails();
bankDetails.setVal(Collections.singletonList(bankDetails));
 }
```

For reference. I have a parent class as BankDetails whose child class is BankExcel

What I am expecting is when there are 2 banks suppose with name - HSBC and RBL at that time when I hit post man I get only one bank as response instead of both the bank.

I expect the response for both the banks

Comment: Assuming `BankDetails` just contains a single value, why aren't you just returning a `List<Bank>`, i.e. a json array that contains the bank objects? Some may seem to think that instead of returning a 1-element array (`[{...}]`) they'd just return the single element if there aren't any more and only return an array/list if there are at least 2 elements but I'd argue against that: if there _can_ be more than 1 element I'd _always_ return an array.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted already contains several issues:

1. The code wouldn't compile as `res.listIterator().next` should be `res.listIterator().next()`
2. you're only getting *one* bank out of the list: `res.listIterator()` returns an iterator that starts at the first element of the list
3. You're not really doing anything with `bank` or `ban`.
4. You're returning a basically default `BankDetails` instance with the only non-default thing is you calling `setVal(...)` (see next)
5. Depending on what `setVal(...)` is doing `bankDetails.setVal(Collections.singletonList(bankDetails))` seems to create a circular reference - not the best thing to do if you want to serialize this to json

With that said, there's a couple of things missing from your post which make it hard to even *guess* what might be the problem you're facing:

- we don't know the structure of any of your model classes, e.g. what does `BankDetails` look like?
- you state there's a relation between some endpoint and an excel file which you didn't show. The method you posted, is that the controller method, i.e. the endpoint? If not, can you share more details no this? And if it is, where does the bank info come from?